# karma angular test router navigate

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm developing an angular exercising app and testing it with Karma and Jasmine. I'm trying to test router's navigate functionality. The problem is that this call is inside a then(). I suppose something is not working because is async. The error: Expected spy navigate to have been called with:[ [ '/error' ] ] but it was never called. How can I resolve it?
My ts:

```
  myFunction(): void {
    functionWhichReturnsPromise().then(() => {
      this.router.navigate('/error');
    });
  }
```

Spec file:

```
describe('myComponent', () => {
  let component: myComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent>;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [myComponent],
      providers: [],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn('functionWhichReturnsPromise').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call navigate', () => {
    const spyRouter = spyOn(router, 'navigate').and.resolveTo(true);

    component.myFunction();

    expect(spyRouter).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/error']);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular lets you synchronously simulate the passing of time of an async function by wrapping your test function in `fakeAsync`, then using `tick(ms)` where ms is the number of millisecond you want ellapsed.

With your code:

```
 it('should call navigate', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spyRouter = spyOn(router, 'navigate').and.resolveTo(true);

    component.myFunction();
    tick() //might need to specify a number of millisecond 
           //depending on what 'myFunction' does

    expect(spyRouter).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/error']);
  }));
```

[FakeAsync doc](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync)
Note that in you case, depending on what your promise does, `flushMicrotasks()` might also work instead of `tick()`